# WooCommerce Subscriptions MySql to Get Historic Subscription info

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have Subscription data in WooCommerce. If I want to perform simple actions like seeing how many Active Subscriptions there that is easy. However, I want to be able to see how many Active Subscribers there were for any given month historically, including the Product Type.

I have the following query which gets all Subscribers and Product Type but whether Active or not seems to be boolean i.e. if someone has cancelled their sub it's Cancelled whereas I would like to see what it was in December for example when I know it was Active. Is there a query that will let me get this information for past months?

```
SELECT
  p.ID as 'Subscription ID',
  p.post_status as 'wc-active',
  pm1.meta_value as 'Billing First Name',
  pm2.meta_value as 'Billing Last Name',
  pm3.meta_value as 'Billing Email',
  oitems.order_item_name as 'Product',
  pm4.meta_value as 'Order Total',
  pm5.meta_value as 'Order Tax',
  p.post_date
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON pm1.post_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON pm2.post_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm3 ON pm3.post_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm4 ON pm4.post_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm5 ON pm5.post_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oitems ON oitems.order_id = p.ID
WHERE
  post_type = 'shop_subscription'
  AND pm1.meta_key = '_billing_first_name'
  AND pm2.meta_key = '_billing_last_name'
  AND pm3.meta_key = '_billing_email'
  AND pm4.meta_key = '_order_total'
  AND pm5.meta_key = '_order_tax'
  AND oitems.order_item_type = 'line_item'
  AND p.post_date < '2021-12-31 23:59:59'
  AND p.post_date > '2021-12-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible unfortunately without taking a few leaps of faith. There isn't any record in the database, that I'm aware of, of when a subscription is cancelled. In theory for each non-active subscription you could calculate when each subscription expired using the post_date and the length of the subscription, but this won't account for cancelled or failed ones.

Comment: Thanks @Kadament but when a member cancels their subscription, that has to be recorded in the database somewhere surely, otherwise how do we know their subscription is cancelled?

Comment: I believe the subscription status uses the post_status field in the posts table. So this will say either active/cancelled/expired or something similar, but unfortunately this doesn't tell you 'when' it was cancelled. There is a post_modified field for the posts table but this can't really be used for this purpose reliably in the case that the subscription has been updated since the status changed.